# Invoking an action before the back button is honored?

Tags: javascript, html5-history

I am adding HTML5 history support to my application.

I'd like to invoke `history.replaceState()` every time the form is modified so that when the user navigates away and back the form looks just like the user left it.

Unfortunately, it looks like hitting the back button does not trigger `onblur` and `popstate` is only invoked after the browser has honored the back button (at which point it is too late to save the form). What event can I listen to that will get triggered **after** the user hits the back button but **before** it is honored?

Comment: There's no such event, there is `onbeforeunload` etc. but that won't really help much either. You have to use an interval that saves the from regularly, and just return to the last saved state.

Comment: Please be sure to disable this functionality for passwords or sensitive fields!

Comment: @Katana314, what attack vector are you concerned about?

Comment: @Gili If you're navigating to a new page, you have to save the form's information somewhere. Generally, it's a bad idea to save passwords in your own storage mechanism (local storage, cookies, etc).